# Terminating app due to uncaught exception, -[FIRInstanceIDTokenInfo isFresh]

Tags: swift, firebase, swift4

When I run my app for the first time, it works perfectly fine. The second time I try to open the app It gives me this Error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

I have macOS Mojave (10.14.3).I am running my iOS application on Xcode 10.3. My swift version is 4.

This is the Complete error Error Message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FIRInstanceIDTokenInfo isFresh]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x172c6cb40

I am guessing the second time I run the app, it cannot connects to the Database. But it's just my guess, I cannot really test it.

Comment: Make sure your Pods are up to date.

Comment: Try to add Exception Breakpoint and find where the exact error occurs then provide this code with a question so we understand the exact reason behind this Error

Comment: Troubleshooting is a good first step to resolving issues. In this case, add a breakpoint to your code, run it, and then step through it line by line until it crashes. Then you can examine the variables to see what is not what you expect it to be. Once you've narrowed down the problematic section of code, include it in your question so we can duplicate the issue. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you resolve this ? I am experiencing the exact same issue